# Sortable.js/Vue..Draggable@next initial order of elements is incorrect

Tags: vue.js, draggable, sortablejs, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

Inital array order is not preserved and changing itemKey prop does not affect the order too. Are the any quick fixes of these issues?

Comment: Not if you don't have any codes to show

Comment: You have plenty of examples here: https://sortablejs.github.io/vue.draggable.next/#/simple The item slot only is available and there is no control over items order. Passed array is changed into Proxy under the hood.